# How to retrieve localStorage data on a Sveltekit page.js file?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I'm new to Sveltekit and I'm trying to share data among different routes. I know the stores are stored in memory and disappear when we change routes, that's why I'm using localStorage to persist data among routes.

**src/stores/stores.js**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const storedUsers = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

export const users = writable(storedUsers);

users.subscribe((value) => window.localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(value)));
```

When my application starts I'm able to update my store on the `src/routes/+page.svelte` default route by doing something like that:

**src/routes/+page.svelte**

```js
<script>
    import { users } from './stores/stores.js';

    function addUser() {
        users.update(list => [...list, `user-${list.length}`]);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={addUser}>Add User</button>
```

However, when I try to retrieve this list from another route (using +page.js) I'm receiving `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I know this code is running on Browser, then why `window` is not defined? And how can I retrieve the localStorage data?

**src/routes/mylist/+page.js**

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

export async function load() {
    const myList = await JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('mylist'));
    console.log({ browser, myList }); // browser is true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Load functions from `+page.js` actually run both on the client *and* on the server. That's why you're getting that error.

The simplest solution is not to use `localStorage` at all. I think what would be the best idea for your case is to use [sveltekit hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks), together with the `locals` parameter.

The scaffolding would look like this:

```js
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';
 
export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  event.locals.user = /* your things */;

  return await resolve(event);
}) satisfies Handle;
```

If you want to keep using `localStorage`, I think you would just need to check if you're in the browser on the load function (best way is to use [the `browser` const that sveltekit exports](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser)), or do the data "fetching" in `+page.js`, using the `onMount` callback.

Comment: Would say it depends on what the data is. A list of users probably does not belong in `localStorage`, though it might just be an example or a prototype for learning.

Comment: Hey, @Odilf, thanks for your answer, however, I wasn't able to understand how this tool can help my use case. Would you mind putting a little example, please?